# How to open links in default browser inside InApp Browser on PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm developing an PhoneGap app and I have little problem.

Inside the app in phonegap I open local link with the InAppBrowser

```
window.open('example.html', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

when I'm in the **example.html** webpage I can't do anything with PhoneGap because is like it was the default browser inside the app.

So, my problem is, I want to open a link with the default browser in the **example.html**, but I can't use the InAppbrowser's statement `_system` because I'm not inside the app and don't run phonegap commands.

**Index.html**

```
window.open('example.html', '_blank', 'location=no'); // Open in InApp
```

**example.html**

```
link2 => www.google.es -> I want to open in default browser.
```

Thank you very much if you could help me.

Comment: Hi, did you got solution???

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this as a workaround (opening an inappbrowser instance):

```
// Image zoom
$('#container').on('tap', '#content.cmscontent img', function() {
    var browser = window.open((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ? 'file:///android_asset/www/' : '') + encodeURI($(this).attr('src')), '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=yes,enableViewportScale=yes,transitionstyle=crossdissolve');
});
```

See I added `(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ? 'file:///android_asset/www/' : '')` as a prefix before the url. Now it detects when you're app is on Android and adds the local URL in front of it.

Comment: Actually he asking something different. 1. index.html, he coded to open inappbrowser-index.html in InAppBrowser(var ref=window.open('inappbrowser-index.html', '_blank', 'location=no');. Now when he run the project on device its opens the inappbrowser-index.html in InAppBrowser. So there are no issue on that. But inside the inappbrowser-index.html, he having link of google. So when he click the link its also opening in same InAppBrowser. So he don't want that. Instead he want the google link should open in Native Browser.